# Need to add an add method, but I get different errors each time which I don't know the meaning of

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, compiler-errors, incompatibletypeerror

In this homework problem we’ll finish implementing the SimpleList interface shown above in a class called SimpleArrayList. We have provided starter code for you including a constructor that takes an initial array of Object references. We are also providing code for the get, set, and size methods—which you completed yesterday—and for remove, to give you an idea of how to approach add. Note that at this point we are testing the entire interface shown above. Your job is to complete add. Like set, you can ignore invalid indices. We will test them.

my code makes sense logically but won't compile

```
public class SimpleArrayList {
    /** Internal array for storing values. */
    private Object[] array;

    /**
     * Create a list from an array of Objects.
     *
     * Copies references from the passed array so that
     * modifications to this list will not affect the original array.
     * We'll need to make copies of the array later to support add and remove,
     * so this is the right thing to do now.
     *
     * @param originalArray original array of Objects used to create the list
     */
    SimpleArrayList(Object[] originalArray) {
        // Would normally need to defend against originalArray being null,
        // but we'll defer that until later.
        if (originalArray != null) {
            array = new Object[originalArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
                array[i] = originalArray[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public Object get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= array.length) {
            return null;
        }
        return array[index];
    }
    public void set(int index, Object element) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= array.length) {
            return;
        }
        array[index] = element;
    }


    public int size() {
        return array.length;
    }

    public Object remove(int removeIndex) {
        if (removeIndex < 0 || removeIndex >= array.length) {
            return null;
        }

        // remove returns the item being removed
        Object toReturn = array[removeIndex];

        // Create and populate our new smaller array. We use for loop syntax
        // maintaining two indices.
        Object[] newArray = new Object[array.length - 1];
        int originalIndex = 0;
        for (int newIndex = 0; newIndex < newArray.length; newIndex++) {
            // Skip the spot that we are removing
            if (newIndex == removeIndex) {
                originalIndex++;
            }
            newArray[newIndex] = array[originalIndex];
            originalIndex++;
        }
        array = newArray;
        return toReturn;
    }

      public void add(int index, Object element)
    {
        Object[] newArray = new Object[array.length + 1];
        int orIndex = 0;

        for(int i =0; i< index; i++)
        {
            newArray[i] = array[orIndex];
            orIndex++;
        }

        newArray[index] = element;

        for(int i = index+1; i< newArray.length; i++)
            {
                newArray[i] = array[orIndex];
                orIndex++;
            }

        array = newArray;
    } 



}
```

all of this was given except for my add method which I wrote. I get different errors right now it says incompatible types for the instantiation of simplearraylist as a list which I didn't even write.

my code makes sense logically but won't compile. all I've written is the add method, everything else was given. I based it off the remove method

Comment: It works fine for me. Maybe you should post the complete error message (copy past from the IDE).

Comment: probably that error is coming from where you are trying to initialize this class. It doesn't come from your add method, since you don't try to instantiate that type there

Comment: How you have initialized simplearraylist in your main method ? can you post your main method ?

Answer (score 0):

It has to implement the interface SimpleList